# Discord bot overwrites data previously stored on json file on every bootup

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am trying to make a currency system for my users with my bot, but everytime I restart the bot, all the accounts and amounts are overwritten and/or deleted.

I have switched how I open the json file and I am opening it is 'a+', but my problem still continues

```
def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'a+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

def _invs():
    with open('inv.json', 'a+') as f:
        json.dump(inv, f)

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def register(self, ctx):
        id = int(ctx.message.author.id)
        if id not in amounts:
            amounts[id] = 100
            inv[id] = ("holder item, ")
            await ctx.send("You are now registered for an account")
            _save()
            _invs()
        else:
            await ctx.send("You already have an account")
```

I hope that when users create an account, they do it once, and never have to worry about it again, but they must keep making accounts and restarting wipes the whole file once somebody makes another account.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're describing. Have you checked if you maybe overwrite the json file at a different point?

Comment: Yes I did check, and no nothing overwrites the file. :(

Comment: with the code you've posted I got this `{"169436847309586431": 100}{"169436847309586431": 100, "169436847309586432": 100}` in my `amounts.json` The problem being it'll just append it to the bottom so you gonna need to change it anyway but it should be saved nontheless.

Comment: The strange part is that this only started happening after I upgraded to rewrite, it worked perfectly on async.

Comment: what do you mean by "worked perfectly on async". As said, from what you've posted I wasn't able to recreate the problem. I assume there's some code missing to find the issue.

Comment: The above code (with w+ instead of a+) had absolutely no issues with the other versions of discord.py, when i upgraded, the only things I changed were the .say functions and the adding cog functions. I have tried this code with w+ but it changes nothing except the json output. It still gets wiped.

Comment: the functions you're using are not related to discord.py but to the python version. So I assume you've changed from python 2.x to 3.x. The only thing I can say is that what you've provided works for me using python 3.7.2. Since I'm unable to reproduce the issue i can only suggest the way I'd handle it and that would be using sqlite.

Comment: I did not use python 2. I have stayed with python 3. Also I will check out sqlite.

Comment: How are you initializing your `amounts` and `inv` objects? Do you have an `on_ready` event?

Comment: yes i do ```async def on_ready(self):
        global inv
        global amounts
        try:
            with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
                amounts = json.load(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Could not load amounts.json")
            amounts = {}
        try:
            with open('inv.json', 'w+') as f:
                inv = json.load(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Could not load inv.json")
            inv = {}```

Comment: @Vreth did you find a solution for this? My JSON data is also being cleared each time the bot is turned off and turned back on since i've upgraded to rewrite. Worked great on async.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening your files in write mode, which discards their contents.  Open them in read mode instead:

```
with open('amounts.json', 'r') as f: 
    amounts = json.load(f)
```

See the [documentation for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more about the various modes you can use to open files and what they do.

Comment: Sorry man, but your suggestion didn't help. I have tried every file mode and it keep overwriting, but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Can you share all of your code that opens these files? After you run your bot, do the files contain nothing or do they contain an empty dictionary?

Comment: When I run my bot, the file contains whatever was in it from the last run, but the bot simply won't read any of that information, and treats it as an empty file. When I invoke a command to edit the file (Registering an account, etc) it wipes the file clean and replaces it. This changes with each file mode, but the result is still the bot reading the file as "empty"